# Possessive case: cosmetic issue prevention or cosmetic issues prevention

Tags: possessives

Which is correct: **cosmetic *issue* prevention** or **cosmetic *issues* prevention**?

(That is, prevention of cosmetic issues. The context is just a title, something like: *Cosmetic Issue Prevention Products*.)

Comment: cosmetic **issues'** prevention

Comment: @AIQ that might work if we're talking about specific issues having been or intended to be prevented. "The issues' prevention was accomplished by ..." but as a general term, like "theft prevention," I'd go with "cosmetic issue prevention." OP should clarify the context where this phrase would be used.

Comment: It would more likely be prevention **of** cosmetic issues.